# Need to unblock remote ps script run using psexec

Tags: powershell, tfs, psexec

As part of our automatic build and deploy using TFS, I need to execute a powershell script on a target server. The following is the (simplified for clarity) command run on the build server by the TFS Build Agent PreBuild step, in the (pre-build.ps1) script...

```
C:\Builds\<snip>\psexec.exe -accepteula -s -i \\WSRMO632WEB powershell.exe \\TFS-BAGENT-POC\<snip>\PreBuild-AppPool.ps1 -name AppPool-DEV -usr User -pw pass
```

If I run the powershell part of the command on the WSRMO632WEB box in a command window, I get the warning...

```
Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, 
this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, 
use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. 
Do you want to run \\TFS-BAGENT-POC\<snip>\PreBuild-AppPool.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"):
```

If I choose R, the script runs and performs correctly.

My problem is that I cannot get the syntax correct to incorporate the Unblock-File cmdlet.

I'm currently thinking that I'm going to have to use multiple psexec commands, one to copy the file from the build server, one to unblock it and a third to finally run it.

Surely it should be easier than that, but I can't find a suitable example and can't get the syntax right.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell's `-command` to first do an `Unblock-File`, then run it as a script.

```
C:\Builds\<snip>\psexec.exe -accepteula -s -i \\WSRMO632WEB powershell.exe "-command \"$file='\\TFS-BAGENT-POC\<snip>\PreBuild-AppPool.ps1'; $file; Unblock-File $file; & $file\"" -name AppPool-DEV -usr User -pw pass
```

Quotes are necessary so that the full command string will be passed to Powershell. Add backslashes to escape themselves as necessary.

UPDATE: You can also try feeding the required command into standard input.

```
echo r | C:\Builds\<snip>\psexec.exe -accepteula -s -i \\WSRMO632WEB powershell.exe \\TFS-BAGENT-POC\<snip>\PreBuild-AppPool.ps1 -name AppPool-DEV -usr User -pw pass
```

This way Powershell will run, get the "R" for "Run once" and run the script, without any changes to the script or calling command.

Comment: I appreciate that I can do this as a multi-step operation (as I said) but I'm trying to do it as a single command. I'm also not sure the "-command \"$file... portion is necessary, I've had successes elsewhere without.

Comment: Oh, that's sneaky!  ;-P It does seem to work but in the end we've decided to develop using an ExecutionPolicy of Bypass then, once we're ready to deploy, sign the scripts. Thanks anyway.